# JTextPane double carriage return

Tags: java, swing, newline, jtextpane

I am using a JTextPane object, let's say its name is **jtp**, so I can show parts of a somewhat short String in *italic* or **bold**. I have a String, let's name it **otxt** that has a newline. Given I am using Windows it means \r\n and it is created using

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

and to dissipate all doubts before they are fully formed, I converted my String to char array, walked the char array and written in the Eclipse console the codes of all characters using implicit conversion via casting to *int* and yes, there is only one code 13, representing \r and only one code 10, representing \n. Now, if I use

```
jtp.setText(otxt);
```

everything goes fine - I do the conversion to char array from

```
jtp.getText()
```

and printing out all characters' codes and I have only one code 13 (\r) and only one code 10 (\n) as I am supposed to have. But I need to show certain parts of **otxt** in *italic* or **bold** so I have to use

```
jtp.insertString(0 /*offset*/, otxt, attributeSet /*italic, bold or whatever stylistic property*/)
```

And here's the big problem: This creates \r\r\n where I am supposed to have \r\n. This is confirmed using the same procedure: 1) string from jtp.getText() to char array; 2) walking the array; 3) printing characters' codes; and I see code 13 (\r) twice and code 10 (\n) once. Help me battle this. Hope you find the question interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Document` class only stores a `"\n"` in the Document. So you should not attempt to insert an "\r" character indo the Document.

If you want to add a newline to the `Document` you just insert `"\n"`.

When you use the `getText()` of a text component the method will replace the "\n" characters in the Document with the newline string for your current platform.

So for Windows the "\n" will be replaced with "\r\n" for you.

Check out [Text and New Lines](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) for more information on this topic.

Comment: I never considered the possibility of \n being replaced by the line separator. Thanks.